# Clearing cached system settings on modx revolution

Tags: caching, settings, system, code-snippets, modx

I have a snippet that updates some system settings by updating and saving modSystemSetting objects. I noticed that old settings are still coming from the cache.

Clearing the cache works:

```
$cacheManager = $modx->getCacheManager();
$cacheManager->clearCache();
```

But this clears the whole cache which isn't good. How could I clear only updated settings? Clearing all systems settings would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [refresh](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/beb66d77a9d05bfa758df76e59bbf9d3497ef854/core/model/modx/modcachemanager.class.php#L528) function in `modcachemanager.class.php`, look at each of the `$providers`.
For `system-settings` try to start with `$cacheManager->generateConfig()` and see from there.  Maybe you'd need more then just the system settings, like [context settings](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/beb66d77a9d05bfa758df76e59bbf9d3497ef854/core/model/modx/modcachemanager.class.php#L57), etc..

If you go further, checkout using custom cache. You can delete specific keys in the cache `$cacheManager->delete($key)`.  See the [Programmatic (Custom) Caching](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extending-modx/caching#programmatic-custom-caching)